# How to use postMessage with the result of a promise in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, postmessage

I am trying to pass an object back to the Renderer using postMessage().

The code resolves fine and creates my object after a series of fetches.

```
loadMainTbls()
.then(retVal => buildMainTbl(retVal))
.then(dat => reduceMainTbl(dat))
.then(res => postMessage(res))
```

If I console.log(res) the proper Array is logged out.  I realize that res is a promise.

```
.then(res => postMessage(new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(res)
})))
```

When I try to resolve res,  it always comes back as an array with length of zero.  On some attempts, I received a # Could not be cloned error.

I've tried to visualize what I could be doing wrong with no success.  Could someone help me to be able to take the promisevalue and post Message it back to the renderer.

Comment: Note that `.then(res => res)` is entirely superfluous, you can remove it entirely, and if the other functions only accept one argument, you can simply pass the function name rather than passing an anonymous arrow function (would make your code a lot cleaner)

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is, might you just `postMessage(res); return res;` if you want the consumer of that big promise chain to be able to access the result?

Comment: Your first point was taken. Next, I can't understand why 'long' promise chain can be logged out, but I can't postMessage() it along.

Comment: In the first block of script, `res` can't be a promise because you can't  fulfill a promise with a promise. Please clarify what you meant by "I realize that res is a promise." In the second block of script you can't `postMessage` a promise because they are not [serialisable objects](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#section-serializable-objects).

Comment: I meant that res is the last link in the promise chain.  The result of that chain is an array.  If res is not a serializable object, I cannot use it in a post message.  What can I do to change res into a serializable/ clonable object?  I'll checkout the article - are you saying I can't get the data into a form that can be passed along with postMessage?

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer is that, I didn't have a thorough understanding of the concept of Promises.  After researching and shifting my mind from a synchronous line after line execution mode into a create promise, resolve promise, .then() mindset.  I was able to solve this question and several others.

I was trying to assign values outside of the scope and execution of the promise - .then() flow.  I learned that If I'm trying to compute something with a promise.  I can do whatever I want at the end of the promise chain.  That the promise chain only executes Promise -> resolve -> .then() or .catch().  Sorry community,  This is 101 stuff, but I learned and understood a very important principle.  Fetch save much time over XHR calls even async XHR calls.